# PreparedStatement and LIKE error

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm programming a simple app in java se with `jdk 1.7`, using `netbeans 7.1.2` and `MySQL 5`.

But i have an error in the next code:

```
String sql = "SELECT idpaciente, ap_paterno, ap_materno, nombres, edad, direccion, telefono, descuento, movil, email, docId FROM paciente WHERE ap_paterno LIKE ? ";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

pst.setString(1, paciente.getApellidoPaterno());

ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
```

This code compiling good, but after execute,i have an error of syntax, netbeans says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?' at line 1

Using debugger of netbeans, the error is in executeQuery, but i can not find my error.

Comment: I think you have missed single quote at '? '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) does not take any argument, however since the interface inherits [`Statement.executeQuery(String sql)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) you are calling that instead.  Just call:

```
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I try this and OK. My app is Ok. That's right, i was using a parameter in method PreparedStatement.executeQuery, this is my error. My problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=33182

The above link has some discussion on this topic. Apparently preprared statements don't work for 'like' and 'in'.

So the problem is that the prepared statement fails to substitute the ? and the resulting query is not correct. The error you see comes straight from mysql.